# PayPal payment simple example in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I'm creating a PayPal payment method for my ASP.Net website. I'm looking at PayPal API docs but I feel lost in it.

I have a simple cart and I want to implement the simplest way to send to PayPal payment information and retrieve payment status.

Can you point me to a simple example, documentation or steps to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This might be of help:
http://indiandotnet.wordpress.com/2009/04/14/simplest-paypal-integration-with-aspnet-in-5-steps/

Here's the reference to the name value pair api with examples:
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_NVPAPIOverview

Answer (score 0):

I can also recommend encores paypal sdk if you want to get started quickly. It's not free but I've been using it for a year now and am extremly happy. (No I'm not affiliated..:-))
http://www.encoresystems.net/